# How to test if a php post request with data from server (not directly from user) was successfully sent?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

my task is to post data from server and not directly from a user(with its ip address). i hope you can help! :)

Code first:

```
<?php
add_action('init', function() {
  if (isset($_POST['form_submitted'])) {
    $data = ($_POST);

    // send data via post request to server
    $destinationUrl = getenv('VALIDATION_URL_DESTINATION'); // get URL from enviromnent variable

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($destinationUrl, false, $context);

    // if status code 200
    if ($http_response_header[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") {
      echo "<p>Post data successfully sent.</p>";
    } else {

      // if status code not 200 -> wp_mail()
      $to = getenv('VALIDATION_EMAIL'); // get email adress from enviromnent variable
      wp_mail($to, "", strip_tags("Post data could not be sent."), "");

      // redirect to form and display error message

    }
  }
});
?>
```

By submitting a form I get some date through a php request. I would like to send this data to a certain destination url and email myself if the status code is not "200" and display an error message to the last visited page (form.php).

I have certain questions:

1. How can i test locally if my code is correct and really sends the data trough a post request? Do I have to use a second server to test it? (I work with valet or mampp and wordpress)
2. How can I force the script to display a message on the last visited page?
3. How can a third person knowing about the structure the data was sent access to the data? For example: He/She fills out the form and submits. If the data was successfully sent it be nice if the data were in a certain format like
   ?first_name=lorem&last_name=ipsum&...

Comment: for the first question : you test the answer of the request in the code you put in the question. then that looks like enough for me.

Comment: if ($http_response_header[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")

you mean this part?